# TexStudio crashes when "Compile and View" in High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: homebrew, preview, latex

I use a macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 and I try to "Compile and View" a text with TexStudio 3.1.1 but the program crashes and quits when the PDF Viewer is selected to be embedded in the app.

I must say that the functionality of "Compile" works fine, as well as "Compile and View" in external PDF Viewer. However, I am interested in having the preview inside the app since it makes the workflow smoother. I tried everything I could and followed [the proposed solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560314/texstudio-3-0-0-quit-unexpectedly-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-6) of installing older versions of TexStudio (2.12.22). Unfortunately, none of them solved my concern.

Thanks,